# Would changing 1 byte in a file encrypted by AES CBC cause it to not be able to decrypt anymore?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

If I have an encrypted file that is encrypted with AES CBC, would changing a random byte somewhere in the file cause it so that it would no longer be able to be decrypted?

Is my understanding correct that everything up to the point where the byte was changed would decrypt okay, but from then on afterwards it wouldn't decrypt?

Comment: AFAIK, it would usually still decrypt, but would give you a different plaintext.

Comment: if padding is used and the last block is decrypting to a different plain text, then the implementation **may** report back an error. In e.g. Java you would get a BadPaddingException if the plain text cannot be un-padded.

Comment: @owlstead: Yes; that's why I said _usually_.

Comment: @SLaks you are right of course, though I was just trying to expand it a bit further, removed ref. to your comment

Comment: Even if the last block is changed, the probability is higher than one in 256 that it will decrypt to a depaddable block anyway.

Comment: @HenrickHellström It depends on the padding algorithm, for PKCS#7 it would only be very slightly higher than 1/256 (+ 1/65536 + even smaller number etc.). If bit padding (rfc1321) padding is used, then the chances of a correct padding is either the same as PKCS#7 (if octets are assumed) or about 1 if bits are assumed. Then there is the deprecated ISO 10126 scheme which probably has a chance of 16/256 for getting a correct padding.

Comment: @owlstead: Yes, there are probably not that many commonly used deterministic padding schemes that would result in a lower probability than 1 one 256.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not quite correct. AES encrypts/decrypts data in blocks (128-bit blocks, specifically). Additionally, in CBC mode, the encryption/decryption of the (i+1)th block depends on the 
(i)th block.

So if the random byte falls within the ith block (let's assume for simplicity that the byte doesn't cross between two blocks), when you go to decrypt the ith block, it will give you the wrong decryption (i.e. a block of 128 bits will be incorrect). Additionally, since the next block was encrypted using the ith block, the (i+1)th block will also decrypt incorrectly (another 128 bits aka 16 bytes). From there, the subsequent blocks will be correct (as will all of the previous blocks).

For more info, I'd read about [Modes of Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) on wikipedia.

One more thing: changing the random byte will likely not prevent decryption from happening - it will just not yield the original plaintext (of course).

Hope that helps!

Comment: If the incorrect byte is in the padding, then the whole decryption may throw a "Bad Padding" error, as @owlstead said.

Comment: @mrfrankli I'm a bit confused at why a 1 byte change to the plaintext before encryption would change every subsequent block, but the same is not true for a 1 byte change to the encrypted text before decryption doesn't change every subsequent block after decryption. I read the wiki page, but was still unsure. Do you think you could explain it a little further why that is the case?

Comment: During the calculation of the cipher text, the last cipher block is XOR'ed with the plain text. If you change anything of the plain text, then the crypted block of that plain text is altered, changing the vector XOR'ed with the plain text in the next block, all the way to the end. If you change the cipher text, then the plain text of that block is changed. The vector XOR'ed with the plain text of the next block is also different, resulting in a single byte loss in that block. Hoever, as the cipher text of the subsequent blocks is not changed, the vector for the next blocks is ok.

Comment: Kyle, just implementing CBC using single block ECB encoding and running it through a debugger can really visualize the whole process, implementing CBC is not hard at all.

Comment: Note that a single modified byte within the `i`th ciphertext block will result in the entire `i`th plaintext block being garbled, but alter only one single byte in the `i+1`th plaintext block - and altered in a predictable way.